# Protect an array of multiple ranges in google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```js
var outputArray = [];
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

for (var i = 27; i < 841; i += 24) {
  (cellvalue = ss.getRange("A" + i).getA1Notation())
  outputArray.push(cellvalue)
}

var protection = ss.protect()
var unprotected = ss.getRange(outputArray)
protection.setUnprotectedRanges([unprotected])
```

I have tried this every which way and I get this error `"Exception: Range not found"`. If I change unprotected to `ss.getRangeList` is doesn't work either. Or if I just change `outputArray` to a range such as "A27, A54" still range is not found. It seems to only like have one set range. The only way I have found around it is to classify each range in unprotectedranges i.e. `protection.setUnprotectedRanges([ss.getRange("A27"), ss.getRange("A54") etc..])`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to protect the ranges of `outputArray` in your script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this modification, I used your `outputArray`.

```js
function sample1() {
  var outputArray = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 27; i < 841; i += 24) {
    var cellvalue = ss.getRange("A" + i).getA1Notation();
    outputArray.push(cellvalue);
  }

  // I added the below script.
  ss.getRangeList(outputArray).getRanges().forEach(range => {
    var p = range.protect();
    p.addEditor(Session.getEffectiveUser());
    p.removeEditors(p.getEditors());
    if (p.canDomainEdit()) {
      p.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the ranges of `outputArray` are protected.
- When you want to remove these protected ranges, you can use the following script.

  ```js
  function sample2() {
    var outputArray = [];
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    for (var i = 27; i < 841; i += 24) {
      var cellvalue = ss.getRange("A" + i).getA1Notation();
      outputArray.push(cellvalue);
    }

    // I added the below script.
    ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).forEach(p => {
      var range = p.getRange().getA1Notation();
      if (outputArray.includes(range)) {
        p.remove();
      }
    });
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [protect() of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect)